# mysql query to match sentence against keywords in a field

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a mysql table with a list of keywords such as:

```
id | keywords
---+--------------------------------
 1 | apple, oranges, pears
 2 | peaches, pineapples, tangerines
```

I'm trying to figure out how to query this table using an input string of:
John liked to eat apples

Is there a mysql query type that can query a field with a sentence and return results (in my example, record #1)?

Comment: your life would be exceedingly easier if you could break your multi-valued keywords into separate rows.

Comment: very true, and I do that for other applications however for this one it's not really neccessary, just needed a quick and easy way like the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it could be to convert `apple, oranges, pears` to `apple|oranges|pears` and use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) (ie regular expression) to match against it.

For example, 'John liked to eat apples' matches the regex 'apple|orange|pears'.

First, to convert 'apple, oranges, pears' to the regex form, replace all ', ' by '|' using `REPLACE`. Then use `RLIKE` to select the keyword entries that match:

```
SELECT * 
FROM keywords_table
WHERE 'John liked to eat apples' RLIKE REPLACE(keywords,', ','|');
```

However this does depend on your comma-separation being consistent (i.e. if there is one row that looks like `apples,oranges` this won't work as the `REPLACE` replaces a comma followed by a space (as per your example rows).

I also don't think it'll scale up very well.

And, if you have a sentence like 'John liked to eat pineapples', it would match both of the rows above (as it does have 'apple' in it). You could then try to add word boundaries to the regex (i.e. `WHERE $sentence RLIKE '[[:<:]](apple|oranges|pears)[[:>:]]'`), but this would screw up matching when you have plurals ('apples' wouldn't match '[wordboundary]apple[wordboundary]').

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this isn't more abstract than what you need but maybe good way of doing it.
I haven't tested this but I think it would work. If you can use PHP you can use str_replace to turn the spaces into `keyword LIKE '%apple%'`

```
$sentence = "John liked to eat apples";

$sqlversion = str_replace(" ","%' OR Keyword like '%",$sentence );

$finalsql = "%".$sqlversion."%";
```

the above will echo:

```
 %John%' OR Keyword like '%liked%' OR Keyword like '%to%' OR Keyword like '%eat%' OR Keyword like '%apples%
```

Then just combine with your SQl statement

```
SQL ="SELECT * 
FROM keywords_table
WHERE Keyword like" . $finalsql;
```

Comment: Is not done with sql but an nice solution. If php is an option.

Comment: @winner_joiner thanks, yeah I need to work on my SQL skills some. Should it be more like $sql = "... WHERE Keyword like" . $finalsql;

Answer (score 1):

Storing comma delimited data is... less than ideal.
If you broke up the string "John liked to eat apples" into individual words, you could use the [FIND_IN_SET operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('apple', t.keywords) > 0
```

The performance wouldn't be great - this operation is better suited to [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any direct solution to that type of query.  But [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is a possibility.  If you have a full-text index on the field of interest then a search with `OR` between each word in the sentence (although I think the OR operator is implied) would find that record ... but it might also find more than you want too.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think what you are looking for is completely possible but you can look into Full Text Search or [SOUNDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex).  SOUNDEX, for example, can do something like:

```
WHERE SOUNDEX(sentence) = SOUNDEX('%'+keywords+'%');
```

I have never tried it in this context but you should and let me know how it works out.