# How to get data which contains search item

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have tried the following code to get data which contain search items.

```
$data = mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM product_table
            WHERE product_name LIKE '%$no3%'
            ORDER BY autoid limit $no2,20"
        ) or die(mysql_error());
```

If i try `kids` its works, but trying `Kids Ski` does not work for me. The entry in the database is `Manbi Kids Carve Ski Glove`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because your value is not like "Kids Ski", instead it contains both words separately..

You need to have a look at RLIKE (ie regular expression)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Have a look at this answer..this is similar problem...https://stackoverflow.com/a/9425088/1114536

Answer (score 0):

You could `explode` your condition and check each word separately:

```
$no3 = explode(' ', $no3);
$w = array();
foreach ($no3 as $v) $w[] = "product_name LIKE '%$v%'";
$no3 = implode(' AND ', $w);
$data = mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM product_table
        WHERE $no3
        ORDER BY autoid limit $no2,20"
    ) or die(mysql_error());
```

In case if you want the query to return results if **any** of the given words matched, rather than **all**, change the following line:

```
$no3 = implode(' OR ', $w);
```